# Stuck in initramfs with btrfs root array

Tags: boot, raid, luks, btrfs, initramfs

I am trying to setup a system with three drives with a btrfs raid1, however I get stuck in initramfs if I have more than a single drive in my btrfs root.

My three partitions:
/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt | sdb3_crypt| sdc3 crypt

I am confident that all three drives are unlocked and mapped and it looks like local-premount/btrfs is setup correctly (running btrfs device scan):

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

PREREQ=""

prereqs()
{
    echo "${PREREQ}"
}

case "${1}" in
    prereqs)
        prereqs
        exit 0
        ;;
esac

if [ -x /bin/btrfs ]
then
    modprobe btrfs
    /bin/btrfs device scan 2> /dev/null
fi
```

and I have /etc/fstab using the UUID of the btrfs:

```
# <file system>                        <mount point>     <type>  <options>       <dump> <pass>
#/dev/mapper/sda3_crypt /               btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0       1
UUID=50758399-2529-470f-bc9d-fbac00a41913 /       btrfs   defaults,subvol=@ 0     1
UUID=aed887b8-8354-4aa8-8d10-2ec20e8478b5 /boot           btrfs   defaults          0     2
/dev/mapper/md0_crypt                     none            swap    sw                0     0
```

Any ideas as to what could be going wrong that is stopping my array from mounting and booting with more than one drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, dropbear/busybox is missing the /dev/btrfs-control device node. This is usually set up by udev.

you will need to create it yourself when logged in to dropbear (initramfs):

```
# mknod /dev/btrfs-control c 10 234
```

https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Problem_FAQ#I_get_the_message_.22failed_to_open_.2Fdev.2Fbtrfs-control_skipping_device_registration.22_from_.22btrfs_dev_scan.22